# Why I cannot use strokeBorder on content that conforms to Shape in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a CustomShapeView which basically takes a Shape content, so after importing in to CustomShapeView I want use a modifier that works on Shape, but in my case it does not! I am wondering what I am missing in between?

**My Goal: I want to be able to import a Shape and apply strokeBorder modifier inside CustomShapeView and return it as a view.**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        CustomShapeView(shapeContent: {
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50.0)

        })
        .padding()
    }
}


struct CustomShapeView<ShapeContent: Shape>: View {
    
    let shapeContent: () -> ShapeContent
    
    var body: some View {

      return shapeContent()
            //.strokeBorder(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 10.0))  // <<: Here!!! Why?
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `InsettableShape` generic constraint.

```
struct CustomShapeView<ShapeContent: InsettableShape>: View { // << == Here
    
    let shapeContent: () -> ShapeContent
```

Just go to the `strokeBorder` definition, where `strokeBorder` is defined inside the `InsettableShape` protocol and which is inherited Shape.